# Не вставляется ссылка на viber в виджет футера wordpress

Tags: wordpress, viber

проблема в том, что при добавлении в виджет "HTML-код" ссылки на вайбер:

```html
<a href="viber://chat?number=xxxxxxxxxx" target="_blank">Viber</a>
```

Она проходит через магию php и становится:

```html
<a href="//chat?number=xxxxxxxxxx" target="_blank">Viber</a>
```

А не должна, почему так ?

Использую Wordpress: 5.2.5, Woocommerce 3.8.1, Divi 4.0.7, PHP 7.4

Answer (score 1):

Создайте в корне вашего сайта файл viber.php со следующим содержимым:

```
<?php
header('Location: viber://chat?number=%2B79500000000&text=Здравствуйте!');
exit;
```

Cсылка будет такая:
`<a href="/viber.php" target="_blank">Viber</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Накостылил созданием страницы и с неё редирект на вайбер, работает.

Создать страницу, например, `site.ru/viber` и потом через .htaccess или плагина для редиректов wordpress перекидываете на `viber://chat?number=xxxxxxxxxx`.

Comment: День добрый. А можете чуть подробнее расписать? )

Comment: Создайте страницу, например site.ru/viber и потом через .htaccess или плагина для редиректов wordpress перекидываете на viber://chat?number=xxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Это лучше в [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1072398/edit) добавить (: